# How to use an independent basic authentication in Symfony 4 when using a user entity for authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, basic-authentication

I'm trying to add basic authentication for the staging environment with Symfony 4 (nginx). Unfortunately, it doesn't work so well. If you define a basic authentication in the firewall settings (`security.yaml`), it will automatically use the provider specified in the firewall. As a result, Symfony uses the basic authentication as the actual login. It shouldn't be so difficult to integrate a simple basic authentication? Do I misunderstand something?

**My goal:**

- two independent authentications (no correlation between users)
- if I log in via basic authentication, I should then be able to log in with the user entity via the actual login page. The page should behave the same as if you were not logged in and do not use basic authentication.

I tried to integrate several firwalls...

`staging/security.yaml`

```
security:
    providers:
        our_users:
            entity: { class: App\Entity\User\User, property: email }

        basic_auth:
            memory:
                users:
                    system: { password: 'testpw', roles: ['ROLE_BASIC_AUTH'] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        staging:
            provider: basic_auth
            http_basic:
                realm: "My Basic Auth"

        main:
            anonymous: ~

            form_login:
                provider: our_users
                login_path: my_login_path
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: homepage

            guard:
                provider: our_users
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: ROLE_BASIC_AUTH }
        - { path: ^/$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

I can use it to authenticate myself via Basic Auth, but I am in the staging firewall. When I now try to log in, it always fails. I think this happens because the form in this firewall is not assigned to an authenticator that references to the user entity. And it doesn't switches the firewall automatically to the correct one.

[image: basic auth login]

What is the best practice to implement basic authentication if you use an user-system on your page?

Thanks for your recommendations!

**EDIT:**

If someone ran in the same issue: I found the problem in my case.. take a look at the response of the accepted answer. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL can only be protected by one firewall, the first one that matches will be used, which is why you are getting conflicts.

> When using the Security component, firewalls will decide whether they handle a request based on the result of a request matcher: the first firewall matching the request will handle it.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html

The easiest solution is probably to configure basic authentication at the web server, examples for [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) or [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/).

Comment: Thanks for your response! It didn't worked the first time, but identified the issue. I had in the main-firewall the line `http_basic: ~`. If you set this, once you have submitted the basic auth form, Symfony will try to log in with the same credentials. But of course he couldn't find it in the database. This causes a redirection, which in turn triggers the basic authentication again. It ends up in an infinite loop. It's funny because I removed this line in my question, so you guys could find out the issue. I hope it also helps other people who might have the same problem. Thanks!